# Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform this operation. Azure SQL Server Database vs SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sql-server-azure

I am moving from the "Classic" SQL Server Database On-Premise to Azure SQL Server Database, Unfortunately, One of the procedures that I used to execute is not working for Azure SQL Server Database:

```
EXEC sp_removedbreplication "Database Name"
```

Got the following error using the SQL ADMIN user:

> Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can perform this
> operation.

However, I tried grant the "sysadmin" role via proc, but no success.

```
  EXEC sp_addrolemember 'sysadmin', 'sqladmin';
```

> Cannot alter the role 'sysadmin', because it does not exist or you do
> not have permission.

**I could not find any Server Role directory via SQL SERVER Management studio**

[image]

Comment: `sp_addrolemember` is to be removed method for adding a `USER` to a  **database** `ROLE`; `sysadmin` is not a database `ROLE`, it's a `SERVER ROLE`. If you want to add someone to a server role use `ALTER SERVER ROLE` (and for database roles, use `ALTER ROLE`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the docs for [sp_removedbreplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-removedbreplication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you will see that only boxed SQL Server editions and Azure SQL Managed Instance supports that stored procedure, not Azure SQL Database.

You can see in [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/replication-to-sql-database?view=azuresql#types-of-replication) what types of replications Azure SQL Database supports.